# Wrong password validation message using CakePHP 2.2.5

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a very strange problem, i have created a simple form to add user into db.

The code works very well, the users are correctly saved into db.

But...

I have a problem using the validation, this is an extract of my validate array regarding the password field:

```
public $validate = array(        
    ...
    'password'  => array(
        'rule'     => array('minLength', 4),
        'required' => true,
        'message'  => "La password deve essere lunga almeno 4 caratteri"
    )
);
```

The minLength rule works correctly, but if i try to show the messages doing:

```
debug($this->User->validationErrors);
```

in my controller. I see this output:

```
array(
    'password' => '*****'
)
```

why "*****" ??
I would like to get the message I wrote in the `$validate` array.

This problem only occurs on the **password** field.

Answer (score 2):

That is some stupid "security feature" one had to implement to avoid some careless people to display their database password on their websites (because they forgot to turn debug off).
So if the key "password", "schema" etc is in the array the value will be cloaked.

Just use pr(), var_dump(), print_r() or any other method that does not do that.

PS: you could have found that out taking a look at the code ( https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/Debugger.php#L449 )

Comment: I for one don't think that stopping you from accidentally displaying sensitive information in an error/debug message is a 'stupid "security feature"'

Comment: @mark, does it mean that when i switch debug mode to off I will see the message i wrote in $validate array ?

Comment: no, then you will see nothing at all (that is the purpose of debug=0 == productive mode). debug info will not be displayed then.

Comment: @RichardAtHome make that "annoying" then. in most cases you need to use a different method then anyway to see its content. and if THAT method ends up being in the productive website, the result is even worse (as it might then persist even without debug on).
If you as dev wouldn't be as reckless to leave debug on in productive mode one wouldn't need this scrambling in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Because password is hashed, and has over than 4 chars. You must check password and after validate hash in beforeSave:)

What kind of version of Cake You are using?

Comment: the password is not hashed.....I hash it using beforeSave in my User model. It is not the solution. Im asking why i see **** instead of my message (message i wrote in $validate array in the model)